# Is there a current equivalent of the discontinued "SQL Server English Query"

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I'm looking for a .net engine that provides a way to translate natural English language queries into SQL syntax.

I know that Microsoft used to have a product called "English Query" that done exactly this for SQL and cube queries based on spoken word. They've discontinued this since SQL Server 2000 and I was hoping that there was a fully supported modern equivalent available?

The previous version supported spoken queries such as " "How many blue Fords were sold in 1996?" into

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM CarSales
WHERE Make = 'Ford'
  AND Color = 'Blue'
  AND DATEPART(yy, SalesDate) = '1996'
```

A link to the original ["English Query"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174480%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Why was this closed? Seems like a relevant question to me.

Comment: @casperOne Seriously! What defines this question as being non constructive, non programming related or lacking information?

Comment: Related [What happened with SQL English query?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/886502/73226).

Comment: @MartinSmith: Thanks for that, very insightful. If you want to add your comment as an answer I'd happily mark it correct.

Comment: "I'm looking for a .net engine that provides a way to translate natural English language queries into SQL syntax." - This is considered a "shopping list" question and is closed with the "not constructive reason on Stack Overflow"

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139513/140951 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138721/140951 (there are really a lot more examples) on [Meta] for more information about shopping lists.

Comment: Just Check These Pages..U Might get the answer..

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886502/what-happened-with-sql-english-query

Answer (score 2):

After a little research, I can't find any new modern natural language to SQL translators. There are quite a few research papers on the subject, but no commercial software that I could find.

[Martin Smith's link from comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886502/what-happened-with-sql-english-query)

[The "Why" it was killed](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/718280/english-query)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [SQL-HAL- Natural Language to SQL Translator](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/hons/projects/2000/Supun.Ruwanpura/), software that's white paper from an Australian University claims that in conclusion:

> "Most of the aims of SQ-HAL were implemented successfully.  The program can translate simple natural language queries in to SQL.  It can translate to different types of SELECT queries, which include retrieving data from single or two tables with or without a single condition.  Learning capability of SQ-HAL is also been implemented with some success.  It is not as efficient as expected because it can only detect table names, field names and conditions in the queries but cannot generalise other words such as determining which words can be optional and may omitted in queries."